# Solve an equation with Partial derivatives

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, partial-derivative

If i have the following relation.

$$\sin\Theta_{12}\cos\beta=\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2\sin(\phi_2-\phi_1),$$

and i need to prove that $A_{\Theta_{12}}=0$ considering that

$$A_{\Theta_{12}}= \sin\phi_1\frac{\partial \Theta_{12}}{\partial \theta_1} + \sin\phi_2\frac{\partial \Theta_{12}}{\partial \theta_2} + \cot\theta_1\cos\phi_1 \frac{\partial \Theta_{12}}{\partial \phi_1} + \cot\theta_2\cos\phi_2 \frac{\partial \Theta_{12}}{\partial \phi_2}$$

How I should begin?

I made a first attempt considering that $\frac{(d(sin u))}{(dx)}=cos u\frac{(du)}{(dx)}$ and thus $\frac{(du)}{(dx)}=\frac{1}{cosu}\frac{(d(sin u))}{(dx)}$, however i didn't get the correct answer $A_{\Theta_{12}}=0$. Was my assumption correct?

Comment: One does not _solve_ expressions.  One _solves_ equations; one _solves_ problems.  One may _evaluate_ or _simplify_ an expression, or do yet other things with it.